# JavaFX. Взаимодействие Controller и Aplication

Tags: java, javafx

Я создаю приложение. Есть основной функционал, но хотелось бы видеть его функциональность в виде счетчика. Нужно сделать так, чтобы из класса Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 230, 100));
    primaryStage.setMaxHeight(100);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(100);
    primaryStage.setMaxWidth(230);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(230);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

был доступ к контроллеру. Я хочу в Main взаимодействовать с системой, а контроллером пользоваться только для того, чтобы обновлять значение счетчика.
Можно ли получить доступ из Main в контроллер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте экземпляр `FXMLLoader`, тогда после выполнения `loader.load()` контроллер можно получить из него `loader.getController()`.
И помните, что обращаясь из `Main` к графическим элементам в контроллере запрос нужно обернуть в `Platform.runLater` для выполнения в графическом fx потоке. А можно и не делать и познакомиться с эксепшеном.